# State what this pseudo code calculates and determine its runtime

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, pseudocode

Such a question can be asked in an exam I write soon. I found this in a book but sadly there were no solutions. So I solved it and I hope you can tell me if I did it correctly?

a.) What does the algorithm calculate?

b.) Analyze the runtime of the algorithm based on `n`

```
     Input: Array A of length |A|=n with n >= 2
     Output: Number x
      x := 0;
      for i := 1 to n do
         for j := i+1 to n do
           if x < |A[i] - A[j]| then
              x := |A[i] - A[j]|;
           end if
         end for
      end for
      return x;
```

For a.) I have typed that pseudo code as complete code in java and executed the program. After several comparisons of the outputs I realized that the algorithm calculates the smallest and greatest array element (you can see my code here, if needed: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b27877536f3c9f553500388af78ee962)

b.) I'm not sure how this is done correctly, but I surely gave it a try too:

```
     Input: Array A of length |A|=n with n >= 2     O(1)
     Output: Number x
      x := 0;                                       O(1)
      for i := 1 to n do                            O(n)
         for j := i+1 to n do                      *O(n)
           if x < |A[i] - A[j]| then               *O(1)
              x := |A[i] - A[j]|;                  *O(1)
           end if                                  *O(1)
         end for                                   *O(1)
      end for                                      *O(1)
      return x;                                     O(1)
                                                  = O(n*n) = O(n^2)
```

Comment: "Did I do _X_ correctly" is not on-topic for Stack Overflow, I'm afraid, as it is not helpful to other readers.

Comment: @JoeC I don't see why it shouldn't be helpful for other readers. One might ask the same question as me and find this one, read through the answers and understand. I have asked plenty questions of these kind on Mathematics Stack Exchange and no one has ever complained about it.

Comment: `I realized that the algorithm calculates the smallest and greatest array element` - to be more accurate, it calculates the difference between the smallest and largest elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer in **Part A**: is not true, because `|A[i] - A[j]|` means the *absolute value* and not the *factorial*. For example: `|1-3| = 2`. So, the algorithm calculates the largest difference beteen the array values.

In **Part B**, you are right it is O(n^2), it is called quadratic and you can find more information [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/41analysis/).